# How to check if a variable is similar to a string?

Tags: bash, shell

Trying to find a way to assign user input to a variable then check if that variable's value if similar to any of the strings I have in a text file.

right now i have

```
read -r userinput     ###assigns user input to var $userinput
x=${userinput,,}      ### makes user input lower case in var $x
```

Now that x = lowercase userinput I want to check if x is similar to any strings in a specified text file. Lets say user input is `hi how are you doing today` and a text file contains a string that is `how are you today` the words `how` `are` `you` `today` are in both strings. Is there any way I can match these up these strings and return a value of 0 or 1 sort of like grep? I know this is much easier in other languages then shell but i'm experimenting with basic machine learning in shell. If anyone knows if this is possible let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute the [LCS (longest common subsequence)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), or at least the [Edit Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) between the two strings.

Generally speaking, no language gives you a function to compute those, so you should write the algorithm yourself.

You can take inspiration from [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence), where the LCS (actually different variations of it) is implemented in several languages.

---

Notice that if you want the algorithm to detect that `hi how are you today` is very similar to `today you are how hi`, than the LCS/edit distance algorithm is not what you want, because those two look for ordered sequence and don't detect the shuffling of elements.

In this case, you'd better think of other approaches, like splitting one string in words, looping on those words and checking if each is present somewhere in the other string.

Comment: You must either be from the '60s or have toddlers...` The choice of your word rearrangement is telling `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin can you give more details? I have no clue what you mean :D

Comment: I apologize, that was somewhat of a joke. `"today you are how hi?"` could either be `"today you are how stoned?"`, or talking to a child `"today you are how tall?"`. Sorry for the confusion -- but worth the upvote `:)`

Comment: Ooooh, `hi` -> `high` -> `tall`. Ok, got it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any quick way to do that in shell, however Python has a great library for that called [fuzzywuzzy](https://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/). The method you need is the token_set_ratio method, which returns how much two strings have in common,
ish (look at the link for an explanation). A return value of 100 means one string's words are all contained within the set of the other string's words. Thus, if you are feeling particularly cheeky, you can run this shell command:

```
ret=$(python -c "from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz; print(1) if fuzz.token_set_ratio(\"$x\",\"$(cat your_text_file)\") == 100 else print(0)")
```

Just make sure you have fuzzywuzzy and python-Levenshtein in pip.